# MS SQL Server COLUMNS_UPDATED() Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have been researching audit triggers for some of my sql tables. I came across [this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/pop-rivetts-sql-server-faq-no.5-pop-on-the-audit-trail/) on [simple-talk](http://www.simple-talk.com/).

Now I know that the COLUMNS_UPDATED() function used here is only supposed to be available on SQL Server 2005 and later but it appears to work under 2000 as well. Is this perhaps a classic Microsoft undocumented feature in 2000? Or am I heading for trouble using this method with 2k?

If it is the case that COLUMNS_UPDATED() is unsupported in 2k, can anyone suggest an alternative method of auditing just the changes from a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[COLUMNS_UPDATED()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(SQL.80).aspx) is fully supported in sql server 2000.

Edit:
the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254(SQL.80).aspx) to the docs.

Comment: Could you perhaps link to any documentation, as Books Online for 2k doesn't have anything relating to COLUMNS_UPDATED().

Comment: Thanks for that Mladen. I realise now that I've probably looked right at the section of the CREATE TRIGGER documentation where COLUMNS_UPDATED() is mentioned, thank you for bringing it back to my attention.